# What does the symbol "::" mean in computer science?

Tags: sets

What does the symbol $::$ mean in the following statement?

$\forall{x}\in K :: x \longrightarrow x$

A cycle in a graph is a path that starts and ends on the same node.
Clearly, if nodes in K lie on a cycle, then $\forall{x}\in K :: x \longrightarrow x$.

Look at page 56 in the following.

https://books.google.co.in/books?id=nel4vdeLcqkC&pg=PR7&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Will it possible to cite the source? It will be helpful to understand the context.

Comment: This isn't standard notation (at least not in this meaning). Try to understand what it means from the context.

Answer (score -1):

It is a delimiter between to parts of expression. You can think of it as notation for the English phrase 'such that'.
Read your formula as $`` \forall x\in K \text{ such that } x \longrightarrow x"$.

Comment: This doesn't fit the extract, in which it seems more like "it holds that" or "it is the case that".